# Put pub admob in footer and resize Button image

Tags: android, layout, admob, imagebutton

I create a smal application and i weel put here in google play i went add pub admob in my application

But BANNER admob c'ont go to footer in my fragment look the image

2 problem when i test my application in two deferent smartphone i have sum problem with ImageButton look the image

code my layout citaion.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/ana"
        tools:context="ma.icoz.citation.citaitongo.citation">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1sp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/shar"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shar" />
    <ImageButton
        android:text=""
        android:layout_margin="1sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:id="@+id/next" />
</LinearLayout>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/citation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Montrez-moi quelqu’un qui ait peur d’avoir l’air idiot, et je vous montrerai quelqu’un que vous pourrez battre à chaque fois."
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Image [image]
How i can resolev this problem

Im sorry for any mistaik english is not my language

Comment: What problem with the ImageView

Comment: When I change the phone the ImageButton next , preview,shar does not resize

Comment: That is because you are not setting image size. Its wrap-content

Comment: How i can do it if i went my applicaion turn in smartpfone and tablete

Comment: Refer to this article https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html